# Redux-Form v6 Tracking dirty fields

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a component called 'collapseList' that renders an array of objects using ArrayField.  The data is something like this:

```
[ 
  { item-name: 'shirt', item-Id: 332 ...}, 
  { item-name: 'shoes', item-Id: 320 ...}
]
```

The question is how do I keep track of whether each item in my array is dirty or not?  For instance in my data, I want to know if only the input fields for the shoes object is dirty.  I get updated on dirty when an field changes and I can get the index and key of the object changed, but where do I store this?  I tried to create an object within the component to track it but when I do setState inside say renderField, I get errors saying I can't do that. What do I do?

This is a simplified version of the code if anyone is interested and can help me.

**collapseList.js**

```
class collapseList extends Component {

  handleSubmitter(values) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // handle submission
  }

  renderField({input, label, index, className, disabled, type, meta: {touched, error, dirty, warning}}) { 
    return(
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div className="form-group row">
          <div className={className}>
            <input className="form-control" {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} disabled={disabled}/>
            {touched &&
              ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
                (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderList({ fields, meta: { dirty } }){
    return(
      <div>
        {fields.map((item, index, field) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Field 
                name={`${item}['item-name']`}
                component={this.renderField}
                label="Item-Name"
              />
              <Field 
                name={`${item}['item-Id']`}
                component={this.renderField}
                label="Item-Id"
             />
            </div>
          )}
         )}
      </div>
     )
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmitter)}>
          <FieldArray name="items" component={this.renderList} />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      items: state.listings.list
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(reduxForm({
  form: 'collapseList',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  validate
}, mapStateToProps)(collapseList));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can use reducer to track the form change and save the changed field. The code snippet looks like:

```
    export const collapseList = (state = {
      collapseTemp: null
    }, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case '@@redux-form/CHANGE':
          collapseTemp = {}
          collapseTemp[action.meta.field] = action.payload
          return {
            ...state,
            collapseTemp
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  

I did what you mentioned and made a state list of all changed values.  Then in my component on componentWillReceiveProps I diff'd the values from initialValues and then added it to a list of dirty fields.  This is a strange way of doing it but it works.  Hopefully I can find a better method.